# Android - How to update the View automatically without refreshing or relaunching the activity

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic-ui

I want to know how to update the UI when a new value comes up. I'm using this code, and for this i have to launch the activity again to get the new results or values. Here is my code below:

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler(Records.this.getActivity().getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tempchart.invalidate();
                }
            });
```

Where tempchart is the View (chart) in which i'm going to show the realtime values

Comment: use broadcast receivers to get the updates.

Comment: broadcast receiver only tells when there is change in value. but i want to show the actual data that i'm receiving on real time

Comment: use services, and hit the api with some time limit, say 2mins, and get the refresh data.

Comment: where does the data come from ?

Comment: Data is coming from Ubidots in the form of Json

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: any solution please

Comment: Refreshing the view can be as simple as a `setText` with a `TextView`. You will have to check the documentation of the Chart View you're using